# missing the last element of the line

Tags: javascript, csv, highcharts

I have tones of data in csv file, and when I am trying to make a graph from the data, my javascript does not read the last element of each line. I tried my javascript with another csv file with less data, and it worked fine. I know in Java, you sometimes need to add system.out.println("\n") when you use scanner because it sometimes skips a line so that you can't write input on the console. Is my problem with csv file like that too?

Here is my javascript:

```
function f() {
$(document).ready(function () {
  var arr1 = new Array();
  var arr2 = new Array();
  var arr3 = new Array();
  var dat = {};
  var options = {
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        defaultSeriesType: 'bar',
        zoomType: 'xy',
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Gene'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: name
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: []
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Position'
        },
        minTickInterval: 10 ,
        labels: {
            enabled: false
        }
    plotOptions: {
            series: {
                stacking: 'normal',
            }
    },
    tooltip: {
        formatter: function() {
            return 'Sample: <b>' + this.x + '</b><br/><br/>' +
            '<n>Position: <b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/><br/>'+ 
            '<n>SNP ID: <b>' + arr2[arr1.indexOf(this.series.name)] + '</b><br/><br/>';
        }
    },
    series: []
   };
   $.get('example.asp', function(data) {
   // Split the lines
    var lines = data.split('\n');

    // Iterate over the lines and add categories or series
    $.each(lines, function(lineNo, line) {
        var items = line.split(',');
        // header line containes categories
        if (lineNo == 0) {
            $.each(items, function(itemNo, item) {
                options.xAxis.categories.push(item);
            });
        }
        // the rest of the lines contain data with their name in the first position
        else {
             var series = {
                data: []
            };
            $.each(items, function(itemNo, item) {
                var data = {};
                var hash = {};
                if (itemNo == 1) {
                    series.name = item;
                    arr1.push(item);
                }
                else if (itemNo == 0) {
                    arr2.push(item);
                }
                else //if //(itemNo < items.length-1){
                    {
                    arr3.push(item);
                    hash[item] = 1;
                    data.y = hash[item];
                    if (item === '15') {
                        data.color = 'grey';
                    }
                    else if (item === '3') {
                        data.color = 'blue';
                    }
                    else if (item === '16') {
                        data.color = 'white';
                    }
                    else {
                        data.color = 'red';
                    }

                    series.data.push(data);
              //      dat.push(series);
                }
            });
            options.series.push(series);
        //    dat.push(series);
         }
        });  

        // Create the chart
   var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
});
  }); 
}
```

and here is how my csv file looks like:
[link](https://docs.google.com/a/cornell.edu/document/d/1AJbNBSOSu3ko59rYfr6aotxDRcBKmsvcgQBPQENImKo/edit)

Comment: If the CSV file cotains that much data, doing the csv processing in the client side doesn't seem to be right way to do that.

Comment: Then which one should I use? JSON? Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: What I suggest is do the CSV processing in the backend with python, ruby, perl or whatever suits your fancy, and store it in a structured database not with JS.

Comment: can't access the csv file - permission required.

I would second the idea of parsing the CSV file on the server side.  You don't have to store it in a data base, but your server will be more efficient at parsing the file than the browser will.  Parse the file (I use PHP) on the back end, pass the json_encoded data to the page to load in the chart.

Comment: @MinSunSong, highcharts has been ported in major server side languages.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to reproduce issue on `jsfiddle`, but everything works fine for me, see: http://jsfiddle.net/ZM6A5/

For each line you have x elements, and series.data contains x - 2 elements, which is perfectly fine with your file, where each line starts like `Janet,d, ...` - so two first elements aren't part of data.

Could you point me where is the problem, or recreate on jsFiddle, please?